# How to build a C++ project using mongoose in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, c, include, mongoose-web-server

I try to build a C++ project using [**mongoose**](https://docs.cesanta.com/mongoose/latest/), but I keep getting linker errors.

I tried to use the answer to the existing SO question describing similar symptoms: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12573818/3723423) by `#include` C header using external C linkage:

```
//simple_web_server credited to Cesanta Software
#include "stdafx.h"

extern "C" {
#include "mongoose.h"
}  

static const char *s_http_port = "8000";
static struct mg_serve_http_opts s_http_server_opts;

static void ev_handler(struct mg_connection *nc, int ev, void *p) { 
   if (ev == MG_EV_HTTP_REQUEST) {
      mg_serve_http(nc, (struct http_message *) p, s_http_server_opts);
   }
}

int main(void) {
    struct mg_mgr mgr;
    struct mg_connection *nc;

    mg_mgr_init(&mgr, NULL);    // <== this causes linker error
    ...
```

I keep getting the following linker error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: simple_web_server02, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  simple_web_server02.cpp
1>simple_web_server02.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mg_mgr_init referenced in function _main
```

The location of **`mongoose.h`** is supplied properties > VC++ > Include Directories.

I note also that omitting/including the 'extern "C" {...}' has no apparent effect.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you provided appropriate linker flags?

Comment: Have you provided search directories to the linker?

Comment: Apparently the problem is more related to the specific usage of the mongoose library (i.e. library c code to add to the project instead of a lib) than a dup of on undefined symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't in principle be obliged to provide for `extern "C"` when including `mongoose.h` :  this header file contains conditional compilation statements in order to [ensure "C" linkage](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/master/mongoose.h#L905) when used in a C++ project.

Apparently, you didn't include the library (lib) for the linker.

**EDIT:** If you didn't download/build a precompiled library, you should add the `mongoose.c` file to your project according to [this](https://cesanta.com/docs/overview/build-options.html) explanation.

Comment: I have now compiled mongoose.c and added a reference to the resulting .lib file in Configuration Properties>VC++ Directories>Library Directories but the same linker failures appear. ?

Comment: @SteveR ok, and does it work ?  Or do you have other linker issues ?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. The same link error(s)  ..   unresolved external symbol   ..  still appear.

Comment: What worked was to place copies of mongoose.h, mongoose.c in my project directory and then to 'add >existing resources'    in Solution Explorer as Header Files and Source Files (respectively). I'm afraid that the link supplied to instructions did not explain that, or at least not to me.

Comment: @SteveR  Ok ! I think your issue could be usefull to other users of this library.  I edited the title and the wording of the question to make clear that it's related to mongoose, so that other users of this library experiencing similar problems can find this post more easily.